# How to sort array of dependencies?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, delphi, reference

I have an array of objects. These objects contain functions and procedures, which can have references to each other. I need a sequence, where these functions are declared in a correct order.

Example:

```
   someFunc1 uses someFunc2;
   someFunc2 uses someFunc3;
```

the correct declaration order:

```
someFunc3(){ ... } 
someFunc2(){ ... } 
someFunc1(){ ... }
```

In some cases one function/procedure has references to multiple functions/procedures.

The array looks like this:

```
[ {string: func_proc, array[int]: calledIn}, {}, {}, ... ]
```

- func_proc: the code of the function/procedure;
- calledIn: the function/procedure positions in the array, where this function/procedure has references

Example:

```
[{"function someFunc1()...", []}, {"function someFunc2()...", [0]}, {"function someFunc3()...", [1]}]
```

I'm working in delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm that you are looking for is known as [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: Thank you for the idea ! I found more help here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topological_sort